# Cannot get onClick function to work

Tags: javascript, html

**`html part`** - this is the main document. It has a table with two rows - five cards on each row. Once clicked, it has to flip to show the content. If two cards are the same, then they have to fade out. This code is for the initial part of the game, where I'm trying to get the card to flip onclick, but it is not working. Please help! The reset function isnt working!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="card.css">
        <script src="card.js"> </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="0" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td> <img src="card.jpg" id="a" onclick="card11();"> </td>
                <td> <img src="card.jpg" id="b" onclick="card12();"> </td>
                <td> <img src="card.jpg" id="c" onclick="card13();"> </td>
                <td> <img src="card.jpg" id="d" onclick="card14();"> </td>
                <td> <img src="card.jpg" id="e" onclick="card15();"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <img src="card.jpg" id="f" onclick="card21();"> </td>
                <td> <img src="card.jpg" id="g" onclick="card22();"> </td>
                <td> <img src="card.jpg" id="h" onclick="card23();"> </td>
                <td> <img src="card.jpg" id="i" onclick="card24();"> </td>
                <td> <img src="card.jpg" id="j" onclick="card25();"> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
<html>
```

**javascript part for the first onclick**

```
var isFlipped=false;
function card11()
{
    //if the car has been flipped 

    if(isFlipped)
    {
        isFlipped = false;
    document.getElementById("a").src="card.jpg"; // click to flip back
    }

    //if the card has not yet been flipped
    else
    {
    //the card is being filpped to show the content - a king of spades      
    isFlipped=true;
    document.getElementById("a").src="king.jpg";
    }
}
```

// after 2 seconds after being flipped to the content, it has to flip back automatically

```
function resetFlip()
{
isFlipped=false;
document.getElementsByTagName("img").src="card.jpg";
}
function card12()
{
if(isFlipped)
    {
    isFlipped = false;
    document.getElementById("b").src="card.jpg";
}
    else
    {

    isFlipped=true;
    document.getElementById("b").src="jack.jpg";
    setTimeout(resetFlip,2000);
}
}
```

Comment: Use `alert("message");` messages, to check where your code fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should delete the semicolon: `;` from the function.
for example:

```
 onclick="card14()"
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working here.
please comment the line "the card is being filpped to show the content - a king of spades" to "//the card is being filpped to show the content - a king of spades" in the js file.